# Yeoman: the 'grunt serve' task and relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman. I'm rather new to it. I'm trying to build a project in a subdirectory of my website, and within my index.html I'd like to access files stored in a directory elsewhere on my site. Here's a rough idea of how things are set up:

```
main site -> css -> grid.css
          |      -> main.css
          |
          -> project -> app  -> index.html
                     |
                     -> dist
                     |
                     -> test
                     |
                     -> gruntfile.js etc
```

The problem is that if in index.html I try to use a relative path such as

```
'./../../css/grid.css'
```

(or however many ../s are required to get to the actual file) and then I run 'grunt serve' the server seems unable to find them. So, how can I tell grunt these files exist?

Before when using WAMP and PHP I'd simply have a variable that I could set, and have an include file somewhere that differed between the live environment and my test environment. I'm guessing something similar is possible using Grunt, but I'm unsure as to how I'd insert that variable into the HTML and have it picked up.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What yeoman generator do you use? ( `yo webapp` ?) -And why are you css files outside your project? They should be in something like `project/app/css/`

Comment: I'm using the standard yo webapp generator. The files are outside the project because they're common across several others, and I don't want to have to copy and paste them into the app/styles/ directory every time I start a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your have files located outside your project, then change you Grunt-script to copy the files into the project before running the project.

A better approch I have use a couple of times, is that I create a common project, and uses Bower to include this common-project, in my web-projects.
This would be done by adding a line like this to your bower.json

```
"my-common": "../common/",
```

Then Bower will make sure to package all the files the same way as it would do with other bower-components (jQuery, Bootstrap etc)

In your HTML you would then have to refere to you common files like this `bower_components/my-common/my-file.css`